# Ubuntu 20.04 focal + Lenovo P15s = Rendering artifacts, disappearing images in Chrome

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, google-chrome

We have several P15s in the company, all of them fully updated. No custom drivers installed, vanilla Ubuntu installation that was updated using apt update & apt upgrade

Chrome rendering artifacts and even disappearing PNGs are experienced. Problem solved when hardware acceleration in Chrome is disabled in settings.

Help appreciated greatly :)

Video: https://youtu.be/zd_p3B3xtzU

Regards
Jonathan

[black spots artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMuOt.png)

Comment: Seems have found the issue hardware acceleration n Chrome.

Comment: @David the issue is the artifacts. Disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome is not a solution, it slows Chrome down incredibly making it unusable. Thanks --J

Comment: That might be something you want to bring up to the people that make Chrome.

Comment: The fact that turning off hardware acceleration in Chrome makes the problem go away does not mean it's a problem in Chrome. The more likely explanation is that there's a GPU driver issue.